# SQL to remove duplicated records by ignoring non-letters and non-digits

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, replace

I'm trying to create an SQL query that only leaves "yahoo finance" and remove the others in following dataset. This dataset is a part of InnoDB table.

```
yahoo/finance

yahoo.finance

yahoo. finance

yahoo-finance

yahoo+finance

yahoo finance

yahoo .finance

yahoo . finance

yahoo - finance

yahoo + finance
```

I tried to write an SQL function that remove duplicates by ignoring these characters: /.,+-'. However I failed and I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: To @VMAtm and others -  Really I didn't understand why this question is **Off-topic**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(columnA, '/', ' '), '.', ' '), ',', ' '), '+', ' '), '-', ' '), '  ', ' '), '  ', ' ')
FROM tableA;
```

Comment: it is the dirtiest but it is the most reliable one in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using `LIKE` with a reg-ex pattern.

Perhaps a where clause something like:

```
... WHERE Field LIKE 'yahoo[. -+]finance'
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z ]+$'
```

Above code will match only alphabets and space.

And to delete the other entries try the following code,

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column NOT REGEXP '^[A-Za-z ]+$';
```